Server project can not run client project in blazor hosted WASM application for firefox broswer only
I had develop blazor hosted WASM application. when run blazor application server program.cs can not run client program.cs i.e server project serve the client static assets of www root folder only can not initialize the client . server can not bind with client. This is happened on firefox only . Remaing browsers are fine. what was issue server program.cs not connected with client.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
 
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
// Add services to the container.
 
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<Root>();
 
 
var app = builder.Build();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
 
app.UseRouting();
 
 
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
 
app.Run();

please helpme. thanks
. when run blazor application server program.cs can not run client program.cs
